# Curve Fitting - Suggestions please

Tags: curve-fitting

Are there any good free programs for curve fitting out there? I have MATLAB and Mathematica, but I don't have MATLAB's extra toolkits. I want to fit a function of this form: (K*(c)^a)/x where K,c,a are constants and x is the variable.

Comment: Maple can do what you need, it has a large number of extra packages that come with it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica has a function called `FindFit`. You can perform a fit for a function as I described in the following way:

```
data = Import["data.csv"];
f1 = FindFit[data, (k*(0.4*^-3)^a)/x, {k, a}, x, NormFunction -> (Norm[#, 1] &)]
```

Answer (score 0):

With both Matlab and Mathematica, you can easily perform curve fitting, without any additional toolkits.

Otherwise, you may look at [numpy/scipy](http://scipy.org/), it's quite good for that kind of stuff. Lastly, there are several "clones" of Matlab which you may google, QtOctave comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SplineCloud](https://splinecloud.com/) - it has a free online interactive curve fitting tool. With the help of client libraries for Python and MATLAB you can reuse construed curves in your code.

[Here](https://splinecloud.com/features/curve-fitting/) is an article explaining the benefits of using SplineCloud for curve fitting.